# TortoiseSVN Checksum Mismatch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, checksum, mismatch

Whenever someone working on our project downloads our repository from scratch (SVN Checkout) there are inevitably problems with Checksum mismatch for a few files.

For example, I went through this today, out of 100,000+ files in the repository, 13 of them had the Checksum mismatch error.

This file did not exist on the PC, it was simply checking out the file. I could delete it from the repo, re-add it, and then try and check out again on the new PC and it would fail.

Modifying the file seems to resolve the issue, for example, one of the files is a picture. I modified a single pixel in it, re-added it to the repo and then was able to SVNUpdate on the new PC.

There are several files I can't do this with, so I am left stuck not knowing how to proceed.

Even trying to roll-back the revision on the PC where I deleted it also results in the error.

I don't have files to check in, I don't have the files on my PC, I just want them from the repo. I've tried deleting the whole directory and getting latest again with no success.

At this point I just want to rollback the repo to a particular revision but I can't because when I try I get the checksum mismatch error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any specific regarding these files with mismatch, the same extension? the same path? ... or absolutely random? Would be the case if some hook or program changes files after check out. Might be interesting for you: http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2009/01/25/how-to-recover-from-checksum-mismatch-errors-in-svn

Answer (score 0):

Could be a corrupt repo. If it's OK with you to delete the bad files from all revisions and readd them (which means rewriting the history of this repo) I would look at [Permanently delete a file from all revisions of a Subversion repository](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/permanently_delete_a_file_from_all_revisions_of_a_subversion_repository.html). I would try this on a test/backup repo first since it's so invasive. Good luck and let us know how it went!